# Why the size of the python reference is so large?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[Python: Size of Reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30329286/python-size-of-reference)

Based on the above discussion, the reference size should be bounded as 8 bytes.
However, based on my experience, the size of a reference is around 200 bytes. Specifically, the self.ptr pointing to a set is 224; while the self.last_ptr pointing to a set is 208.

Question> Can we somehow reduce the size the class Hello in python?

```
In [24]: import sys
    ...: from pympler import asizeof
    ...:
    ...: class Hello(object):
    ...:     def __init__(self):
    ...:         self.name = None
    ...:         self.ptr = None
    ...:         self.last_ptr = None
    ...:
    ...: hello = Hello()
    ...: print("0={0}\n".format(asizeof.asizeof(hello)))
    ...:
    ...: hello.name = '0123456789'
    ...: print("1={0}\n".format(asizeof.asizeof(hello)))
    ...:
    ...: a = set()
    ...: hello.ptr = a
    ...: print("2={0}\n".format(asizeof.asizeof(hello)))
    ...:
    ...: b = set()
    ...: hello.last_ptr = b
    ...: print("3={0}\n".format(asizeof.asizeof(hello)))
    ...:
    ...: print("4={0}\n".format(asizeof.asizeof(100)))
    ...:
0=344

1=408

2=632

3=840

4=32


In [25]: 632-408
Out[25]: 224

In [26]: 840-632
Out[26]: 208
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not measuring the size of a single reference.

`pympler.asizeof()` produces the memory footprint of the *whole Python object, recursing to attributes*. An instance object with a `__dict__` dictionary object for the attributes, containing 3 key-value pairs for the attributes, plus a reference back to the class and a weak references section is *not a single reference*.

Quoting [the documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/Pympler/#usage-examples):

> `pympler.asizeof` can be used to investigate how much memory certain Python objects consume. In contrast to `sys.getsizeof`, **`asizeof` sizes objects recursively.**

Bold emphasis mine.

To calculate the size of a single reference, create an empty tuple and a tuple with a single element in it. The difference in memory size (as measured by `sys.getsizeof()`, **not** recursing), is the size of one reference:

```
>>> import sys, platform
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=4, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>> platform.platform()
'Darwin-17.4.0-x86_64-i386-64bit'
>>> sys.getsizeof((None,)) - sys.getsizeof(())
8
```

or use the `__itemsize__` attribute of the tuple type:

```
>>> tuple.__itemsize__
8
```

So on a 64bit OS X system, references are 8 bytes long.