# Memory consumption in Python - lists, subscripting, and pointers

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, memory, profiling

I'm trying to understand how much memory Python objects use.

In the following code, I check the memory of a numpy array vs list as well as a subscripted numpy array:

```
import sys, os, psutil, numpy as np

def size_of(obj):
    return f'{sys.getsizeof(obj) / 1000000:,.0f} MB'
def get_memory_usage():
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    return f'{process.memory_info().rss / 1000000:,.0f} MB'

# Numpy vs List
print(f'(1) Mem usage: {get_memory_usage()}')
ONE_HUNDRED_MIL_NP = np.random.randint(-128,127,int(10**8),dtype='int8')
print(f'(2) Mem usage: {get_memory_usage()}, ONE_HUNDRED_MIL_NP: {size_of(ONE_HUNDRED_MIL_NP)}')
ONE_HUNDRED_MIL_LIST = list(np.random.choice(127, int(10**8), replace=True).astype('int8'))
print(f'(3) Mem usage: {get_memory_usage()}, ONE_HUNDRED_MIL_LIST: {size_of(ONE_HUNDRED_MIL_LIST)}')

# Now try subscriping
FOURCOLS = np.random.randint(-128,127,size=(int(10**8),4),dtype='int8')
print(f'(4) Mem usage: {get_memory_usage()}, FOURCOLS: {size_of(FOURCOLS)}')
FOURCOLS_PERMUTED = FOURCOLS[np.random.randint(0,len(FOURCOLS),size=len(FOURCOLS),dtype='int32')]
print(f'(5) Mem usage: {get_memory_usage()}, FOURCOLS_PERMUTED: {size_of(FOURCOLS_PERMUTED)}')
```

This returns:

```
(1) Mem usage: 187 MB
(2) Mem usage: 287 MB, ONE_HUNDRED_MIL_NP: 100 MB
(3) Mem usage: 3,526 MB, ONE_HUNDRED_MIL_LIST: 900 MB
(4) Mem usage: 3,926 MB, FOURCOLS: 400 MB
(5) Mem usage: 4,326 MB, FOURCOLS_PERMUTED: 400 MB
```

Notes:

1. Output (2) makes sense. One int8 is 8 bits (one byte) and 100 million bytes is 100 MB
2. Output (3) I don't understand:

   1. The first issue is that sys.getsizeof() shows the objects takes up 900 MB, but psutil shows that the process now takes up 3,239 MB more memory (3526-287=3239). Where is this phantom memory usage coming from?
   2. Where does the 900 MB come from? (From [Python: Size of Reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30329286/python-size-of-reference), I'm assuming that there's 100 MB of the numpy object plus 100 million pointers, which are 8 bytes each, so 100 MB + 800 MB = 900 MB?)
3. Output (4) Makes sense. 400 million int8s is 400 MB.
4. Output (5) I don't understand. Is a copy being made or references? If references, we're only referencing 100 million rows, right? How does this make 400 MB?

Thanks

Comment: search on `[numpy] getsizeof` to see previous discussions.  This kind of testing can be confusing if you don't understand how arrays and lists are stored.  `getsizeof` is somewhat useful when applied to numpy arrays - provided you understand the difference between `copy` and `view`.  It's useless when looking a lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
ONE_HUNDRED_MIL_NP = np.random.randint(-128,127,int(10**8),dtype='int8')
```

This makes an  array.  `ONE_HUNDRED_MIL_NP.nbytes` is a good measure of the array size.  An array has some basic info like shape, strides, dtype, but the bulk of the space is a 1d data buffer that contains bytes, in this case on byte per element.

```
ONE_HUNDRED_MIL_LIST = list(np.random.choice(127, int(10**8), replace=True).astype('int8'))
```

This produces a list from that array.  A list has a databuffer that contains references to objects else where in memory. `getsizeof` just measures that size of that buffer, and says nothing about the objects.  Here those objects are `numpy.int8` objects, extracted from the array.  They don't actually reference elements of the array, but rather are copies of those values.

A better way to get a list from an array is with `arr.tolist()`.

```
FOURCOLS = np.random.randint(-128,127,size=(int(10**8),4),dtype='int8')
```

This is just another array. the 2d shape doesn't change how much memory it takes up.

```
FOURCOLS_PERMUTED = FOURCOLS[np.random.randint(0,len(FOURCOLS),size=len(FOURCOLS),dtype='int32')]
```

This is an example of `advanced indexing`.  It creates a new array with its own data buffer (not a `view` with a shared buffer).  Yes, you are just indexing the first dimension, but the data buffer stores all values, not references to rows of FOURCOLS.

A list of lists does store references or points to the nested lists.  So shuffling the outer list would just shuffle the references.  Multidimensional `c` arrays also store references or pointers.  But multidimensional numpy arrays use a different model.  The data is a flat `c` array.  Multidimensionality is produced by the `shape/strides` iteration code.

---

So looking at your numbers:

```
(1) Mem usage: 187 MB
```

base usage.

```
(2) Mem usage: 287 MB, ONE_HUNDRED_MIL_NP: 100 MB
```

adds 100mb to base.

```
(3) Mem usage: 3,526 MB, ONE_HUNDRED_MIL_LIST: 900 MB
```

The 900 is roughly the memory used by the list's data buffer.  The rest of total usage increase is storage for those 10**8 `np.int8` objects.

```
(4) Mem usage: 3,926 MB, FOURCOLS: 400 MB
```

This shows another 400 MB memory usage.

```
(5) Mem usage: 4,326 MB, FOURCOLS_PERMUTED: 400 MB
```

And yet another 400.

Without the (3) list creating `mem usage` should show an orderly increase by the array size.